# My sudo password was completely showing on my terminal - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: command-line, 22.04, visudo

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop, on my PC is normal but with my laptop, everytime I input password for sudo it was showing on screen.

[image]

I trying to edit in visudo but my password still showing on screen

[image]

**Edit:**

I follow your guys and typing "type -a sudo" then get this result

`sudo is /usr/bin/sudo sudo is /bin/sudo`

Notes: pwfeedback was not at visudo in the first time, I was read some password problems and I tried to write it into visudo. I removed it few minutes ago and it still showing sudo password.

Comment: Remove `pwfeedback` from the sudoers file ... That is something you added and not there by default and it means what it says "Password Feedback" ... It should be asterisks `*` though, so you probably modified something else ... Do you recall what it was?

Comment: @steeldriver Nice point ... Might be a password helper program indeed.

Comment: That is interesting ... Please, [edit] to add the output of `sudo --version` and the output of `strace sudo` and the output of `ldd /bin/sudo`

Comment: I can reproduce this (Ubuntu 22.04 VM, sudo version 1.9.9) by enabling `visiblepw` and then invoking sudo in an environment that does not allocate a TTY ex. `ssh localhost sudo sudo -l`. The cleartext password appears to be echoed regardless of whether `pwfeedback` is enabled.

Answer (score 6):

Edit the [`sudoers`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man5/sudoers.5.html) configuration file with:

```
sudo visudo
```

and remove `,pwfeedback` as this enables the password feedback i.e. indicator characters in the terminal which are usually asterisks `*` ... Plain text however is not enabled by that so you probably changed something else as well.

Making [`sudo`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/sudo.8.html) print the plain text password in the terminal is not possible as well AFAIK.

What you might have masking your settings in the sudoers configuration file is likely an intermediate(*between the user and `/bin/sudo`*) password helper program, an executable shell script in your search path or even a shell function like this one:

```bash
sudo () 
{ 
    read -r -p "[sudo] password for ${USER}:" my_pass;
    echo "$my_pass" | /bin/sudo -S "$@"
}
```

You can find out which is which by running in your terminal:

```
type -a sudo
```